# Custom scrollbar style - There is a blank white box in bottom right corner of scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a custom scrollbar and there is a white box in the lower right corner of the scrollable div.

The goal is to remove the plain white box you see in the image below (lower right corner).

I have other div's that are scrollable, using the same classes, but not showing this little white box.

[image]

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
                      <div className="terminal">
                        <div className="terminal-header white-text" style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                          <div className="content-row" style={{ padding: '10px' }}>
                            <PublicIcon />
                            <span style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>Custom Header Options</span>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className="terminal-content white-text" style={{ maxHeight: '250px', overflowX: 'scroll' }}>
                          {customHeaders.length > 0
                            ?
                            <table>
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th style={{ backgroundColor: '#562484', position: 'sticky', top: '0', width: '50%' }}>Key</th>
                                  <th style={{ backgroundColor: '#562484', position: 'sticky', top: '0', width: '50%' }}>Value</th>
                                  <th style={{ backgroundColor: '#562484', position: 'sticky', top: '0', width: '10%' }}></th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>

                                {customHeaders.map((header, index) => {
                                  return (
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>{header.key.length > 15 ? header.key.slice(0, 12) + "..." : header.key}</td>
                                      <td>{header.value.length > 15 ? header.value.slice(0, 12) + "..." : header.value}</td>
                                      <td><DeleteForeverIcon /></td>
                                    </tr>

                                  )
                                })}

                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            : null}

                          {customHeaders.length == 0
                            ? <span style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}>There are no custom headers added to this monitor</span>
                            : null
                          }
                        </div>
                      </div>

</Grid>
```

```
* {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: #623CEA;
    }
  
/* Works on Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #623CEA;
}
  
.terminal-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #562484;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #623CEA;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(57, 57, 57);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following style:

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   background: transparent;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worth noting that this solution (and a lot of the OP's code in general) [will not work in Firefox or Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar), and comes equipped with a warning to not use it in production sites.  For the benefit of future readers if nothing else.